# Nuxt 3.0 /content issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown

I'm adding h2s in a .md file but it seems it doesn't appear on the target page for some reason, what do you think? I've read the Nuxt denomination but didn't a find a solution.

I expect adding headings in .md files to be more smooth. [here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41EIF.png)